# Python - TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, string, list

I keep receiving this type error - `TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`

Here is my code:

```
for key,value in d_facebook.items():
    for anom in anomalies:
        for nested_values in value:
            searchstr = str(nested_values[4])
            if re.search(r'\b' + anom + r'\b', searchstr):
                value.remove(nested_values)
```

I am trying to see if a keyword is within a string.

`nested_values[4]` is a `list` containing the `string` I wish to search. How do I go about converting the list into a string for comparison?

Thanks for any help, please explain the error too! I am very new and assumed the str() function would do the job.

Comment: Can you show us what  `nested_values[4]` looks like?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Calling `str()` is converting explicitly, not "implicitly", so chances are the error is not happening where you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate a list into a string, use `' '.join(your_list)`. To explain the error, well the `str` method has no idea how to implicitly convert a list into a string.

If the elements of your list are not string, you will need to pass each one of them to `str`: `' '.join(str(e) for e in your_list)`.